# Text binding without AngularJS or KnockoutJS

Tags: jquery, text, binding

I'm building a page where users can send push messages. I'll use a textarea where the user can type in a message and I really think it's a cool idea to show his message realtime in an iPhone mockup (text binding). I know this is possible through AngularJS and KnockoutJS but my questions is if there is an easy way to achieve this with jQuery? I've only used jQuery, HTML and CSS for building my pages so I want to know if there is a possibility where I won't have to include frameworks like Angular or Knockout?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, Angular and Knockout are just javascript. To get yourself started, try [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh549259.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the websockets technologies, where you could send push message from a device to other without send resquest-post in every device.

When the user A connect with his PC he is connected for send information to the server and the server can send information to him too, the same will happen with the user B connected his iphone.

With jquery and the help of other library like sock.js you can send the psuh messages to the server and the server send this indformtion to other user without the intervention of the final user.

With this solution you wont need none framework MVVC like angularjs o knockoutjs, and you can build your frontend with html5 and exchange information with your server with jquery and ajax request.

I hope help you.